# The principles of statics without force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, statics, foundations

I'm a student of civil engineering and now my course is covering the basics of statics, such as the equations of equilibrium, etc. Trying to get a better basis on the subject, I started to search on the subject of force and plane statics. I found in https://archive.org/details/ConceptsOfForce the confirmation of what I had already read on Russell's Principles of Mathematics: that the concept of force is totally fictious, and modern science is in a growing tendency of abandon it. My question is: how the principles of statics (specially the equations of equilibrium) would be formulated without the aid of "force"? In Jammer's book, he explains the meaning of Newton's second law (i.e, mass times acceleration) as a function of configuration, but I fail to see how this would apply.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Do you know of the [Lagrangian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) and [Hamiltonian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) formulation of classical mechanics? Neither uses the concept of force directly (except to show equivalence to ordinary Newtonian mechanics). You should also note that, in the usual diction, *fictitious* forces are those that only show up because you chose a particular frame of reference, and there are undoubtedly forces that do *not* vanish under change of frames.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I submit to you [Action-angle coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action-angle_coordinates)

Comment: @lionelbrits: If I am correct in assuming you tell me this because these variables look like a coordinate system in which the Hamiltonian is free, i.e. there are no forces, you should keep in mind that the generalized coordinates of Hamiltonian mechanics are *not* frames of reference in the sense of Galilean or special relativity, hence this would not in the usual sense show that forces are fictitious. If one adopts the broader viewpoint that all forces that come from geometry are "fictitious", then, through this, all forces are, somewhat tautologically, fictitious indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Principles of statics is a consequence of the principle of minimum of potential energy.
You could write down the full potential energy of the system $U(x _1,\ ...,\ x_n)$ and minimize it regarding constraints equations $F_k(x _1,\ ...,\ x_n)=0.$ Doing it using Lagange multipliers you'll obtain equations of static: 
$$\frac {\partial U}{\partial x _i } - \sum\limits_k \lambda_k \frac {\partial F_k}{\partial x_i }=0,$$
$$F_k(x _1,\ ...,\ x_n)=0.$$

You also could find out how is it related to (generalized) forces keeping in mind that force acting to some part of the system is just a negative gradient of the potential energy by the coordinates of this part.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting. I don't want to push it, since you were kind enough to answer, but I have two additional questions for you: (1) there's a similar approach using kinetic energy? (2) I still don't get how could I "transfer" some thing like "a bar with fixed supports with a load of 300N" into potential energy problem. If my question is stupid I apologize, I'm starting at physics now, and wan't to grasp it in the most correct way possible. So if you could give me a practical example it would help a lot.

Comment: 1) If there is a kinetic energy you should use Lagrange or Hamilton formalism. The principle of minimum potential energy is a special case of both of them when the kinetic energy is zero.

Comment: 2) When you have forces then you should include it in the static equation manually with minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the concept of a force is fictitious. I've heard Engineers say that forces aren't real and that there are only couples, but I wonder if this is more about semantics than anything else. It seems like physicists are always inventing new forces! To me, a force is something you put on the right hand side of the second derivative of some quantity with respect to some parameter (akin to the idea of generalized forces in analytical mechanics). Sure, I can almost always choose a parametrization such that the force vanishes, but if you call that fictitious then you'd have to say that dynamics are fictitious too! Personally I'm not going to disagree with that statement, but I don't think it is a position that modern science is gravitating towards.

Comment: You make a valid point, but this doesn't really answer the question (namely, how to formulate a statics problem without forces); therefore, this post is probably better suited to being a comment than an answer.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you're right. Perhaps something about virtual work would be appropriate, then?